main.INFO: Price/Special Price/Final price - (continuously writing thousand of lines)
Why do we see suddenly see the following info in our Magento 2.4.7 system.log (continuously - thousand of lines)
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.075810+00:00] main.INFO: Price: 199 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.075884+00:00] main.INFO: Special Price:  [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.075927+00:00] main.INFO: Final Price: 60 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.076686+00:00] main.INFO: Price: 199 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.076748+00:00] main.INFO: Special Price:  [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.076791+00:00] main.INFO: Final Price: 60 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.077223+00:00] main.INFO: Price: 199 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.077279+00:00] main.INFO: Special Price:  [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.077320+00:00] main.INFO: Final Price: 60 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.078022+00:00] main.INFO: Price: 199 [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.078077+00:00] main.INFO: Special Price:  [] []
[2024-07-04T11:17:09.078119+00:00] main.INFO: Final Price: 60 [] []

Someone added logs to check the price and forgot to remove them. Try finding the line ->info('Price' in your code (and similar lines) and remove it.

Siarhey, Thank you very much.
I found the following lines in an installed module
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger = $objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
$logger->info('Price: ' . $prodPrice);
$logger->info('Special Price: ' . $specialPrice);
$logger->info('Final Price: ' . $final);

@JesperBrejning Great! I think you can safely delete them and free up some space in your logs.
